# Build Failure during deploying maven project to heroku

Tags: maven, jsp, heroku

I am trying to deploy maven project to heroku but it is showing error.

```
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [765 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: 
C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\MakeMyEvent\target\MakeMyEvent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.406 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-23T16:16:19+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war- 
plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project MakeMyEvent: Error assembling WAR: 
webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

it is a jsp project and working fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the information you have provided here, your war building triggers the error.
basically if you are using maven war plugin try considering adding `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>`

Example :

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```